# How can I disable or hide a script from running on my site if being viewed on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile, parallax, skrollr

I know this is a simple one but, I'm just not good enough with JavaScript to get it right.

I have a script I'm using (skrollr.js) to create some animated parts and I do not want this script to run when the site is hit on a mobile device.

The script is simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init();
</script>
```

It works great on desktop but is funky on mobile devices so, I've decided to just disable it all together on mobile.

I don;t want to redirect to a different page or anything... I simply just don;t want the script to run on mobile. How can I make that happen?

Thanks.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery

Comment: Actually, I found the perfect solution here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645655/disable-skrollr-for-mobile-device-767px?rq=1

    $(function () {
      if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        skrollr.init();
      }

      $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
          skrollr.init().destroy();
        } else {
            skrollr.init();
        }
      });
    });

Thank you to [iCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3646748/icoder) for a clean, simple solution.