# skrollr.js creates some unwanted effects on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, skrollr

I am facing issues with skrollr.js , it creates some unwanted effects on mobile.

Looking for a way to disable skrollr.js for mobile or in particular devices with max.width 480px.

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is destroy() method.

**UPDATED**

Option 1:

```
var s = skrollr.init();
if (s.isMobile()) {
    s.destroy();
}
```

Skrollr has its own mobile check function.

option 2:

Use this code..

```
$(function () {
  // initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {  //change the width according to your need
    skrollr.init(yourOptions);
  }

  // disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {   //change the width according to your need
      skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
    }
  });
});
```

For more details please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645655/disable-skrollr-for-mobile-device-767px) here

Comment: Could you please help me with the place i should use the code as i am not that good with using js

Comment: use with <script>tag either in header part, before closing the <head> tag or in bottom of page..depends on you..

Comment: what should come inside your options part